# Is it possible to make Flying Koopas which move horizontally?

Tags: super-mario-maker-2

When given wings, Red Koopas move in a vertical line up and down. Green Koopas simply hop around, and don't actually fly. I'd really like the option of having a Flying Koopa which moves horizontally instead, left and right, but it doesn't appear to be possible. Buzzy Beetles fly horizontally, but  don't actually go back and forth and instead just move in one direction (plus, they behave differently when you jump on them compared to other flying enemies).

Is it possible to make a Flying Koopa with a back and forth horizontal movement? If not, is there any enemy that when given wings, will fly in such a pattern?

Answer (score 7):

You can simply place a red flying koopa on a horizontal track to get the same desired effect.  Granted their moving speed will be a bit faster than normal due to being on the track.  Removing the wings make them slower but you lose the extra bounce hit.

Comment: This would work although it looks ugly